# js doesnt recognize click on navbar collapse button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem, with navbar toggle in twitter bootstrap 3 on small screens (when collapse button appears), 
everything looks fine i think, when i execute my code on jsfiddle collapse button works, but in my asp net mvc project  menu dropdown doesnt appear when i click on button, 
heres code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default scrollMenu" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href=""></a>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="scrollTarget">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
             <li class="active"><a href="/#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>1</li>
             <li class=""><a href="/#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">2</i></a> </li>
             <li class=""><a href="/#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats">3</i></a> </li>
             <li class=""><a href="/#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>4</a> </li>
             <li class=""><a href="/#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-1"></i></a>5</li>
             <li class=""><a href="/#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>6</a> </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: take the rendered html and put it in the fiddle, then check dev tool console

Comment: Are you saying that the dropdown button not appear or it is not working? If the button is not working then check for any javascript issues in your page else find whether your js file is rendered correctly.

Comment: button appears but it is not working at all, i debuged js in my project its not executing click event at all, but when i execute it on js fiddle it works fine